# How to migrate html, css and javascript application into react-native components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I've created a web application using HTML, CSS and Javascript but is it possible to convert it to a react-native app with the help of any kind of **wrapper for HTML, CSS and JS code** which can be used within react-native. I would like to convert the web application component into react-native components though it would be a tedious process if I need to change anything in the web application which in turn lead me to change the react-native components.

Comment: Low effort post... What have you tried? Code snippets?

Comment: Follow the attached link for the same  https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-convert-any-web-page-to-reactjs-9740f1ba15db

Comment: So far I've only worked with single SPA(for web development) to create micro-frontends with muliple frameworks and libraries like angular, vue or react but even with single SPA, it is not possible to wrap html codes even if I could do it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use html,css,and javascript code for  react native app. Beacause react native has its own tags so it wouldn't possible but still if you can follow the attached url hope it may give you ideas

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-convert-any-web-page-to-reactjs-9740f1ba15db

Answer (score -1):

a method would be...
react-native-WebView? I haven't tried it out but from what it sounds like I think its like android web view where u can give it a link and it will load that webpage? that's the closest thing I can think of. of course this method has limitations obviously...

I don't think there are any good methods to turn react code to react-native code since both have different tags and even if you do somehow do it you will have to climb mountains of bugs and fixes if your app is kind of complex.

but if in the future u do take up a project that is for both web and native, and they both share a load of functionality I would recommend  something like react-native-web where you can share a codebase between web and native. essentially by making a native app ur making a web app aswell. its a bit tricky when u start but if your having projects like this it will be helpful. hope this gives u some ideas